# Google Sheets: Can I copy the CheckBox display from a sheet to another =QUERY subset of a sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Can I copy the CheckBox display from a sheet to another.

Image tab 'a-sheet' columns B & C where formatted as checkboxes (Menu > Insert > Checkbox)
Can a new

```
=QUERY('a-sheet'!A1:ZZ999,"SELECT A, B, C",1)
```

I have found that you can do (Menu > Insert > Checkbox) on an individual result, but not the whole set of `=QUERY` results.

Comment: *"the CheckBox display"* Also *"Image tab 'a-sheet'"*. Could you please use a sheet instead of just wording your questions? Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: @marikamitsos not sure what you're asking. The SHEET is simply in A1 =QUERY('a-sheet'!A1:ZZ999,"SELECT A, B, C",1)   Fields in the master sheet have "checkboxes" and when transfer by =QUERY become TRUE/FALSE and do *not* display as checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it. **Unfortunately checkboxes do NOT carry over.** The only workaround would be to select all the resulting `TRUE/FALSE` cells and choose insert Tick box from the menu. **You can also try using a script.** Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55745594) in StackOverflow

Comment: Have you tried filtering the data, then copy/paste the (filtered) data range?

Answer (score 1):

There may be many ways to answer this question. Please consider this as just one solution.

**Create a filter**

- Select the data columns, then from the menu select: Data > Create a filter. The filter icon will appear in the header of each column.

**Select the "true" values**

- Click the filter icon for Column A, and select only "True" values, then click "OK".

**Copy and Paste the data**

- Select the range of "True" values, including the headers. Select from the menu: Edit>Copy.
- Select the cell where the data is to be copied (on the same sheet or another sheet). Select from the menu: Edit> Paste.

Note that only the header and rows containing the "checked" checkboxes are copied.

---

**Create a filter**

[image: Create a filter]

---

**Select the "true" values**

[image: Select the "true" values]

---

**True values**

[image: True values]

---

**The copied data**

[image: The copied data]